# How to add SVG image to vuetify text field

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify and would like to add an SVG icon to the start of the text field. I know you can prepend or append icons from v-icon, but I would like to use my own SVG image in a similar way.

Comment: Read up on the documentation about [custom icons](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/icons#using-custom-icons).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the "prepend" slot:

```
<v-text-field label="My text field" type="text">

    <template v-slot:prepend>

      <img width="24" height="24" src="[PathToAssets]/whatever.svg" >

    </template>

  </v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read about the [public path](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder)

I would strongly recommend using the public path:

Add your svg image to `public/img/icons/test.svg`.

Use the img tag like this `<img src="/img/icons/test.svg">` to point to the svg location.

If you really dont want to use the public path for your svg's you can use this loader to import your svg's: https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader